# Build Error: 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Columns', 

Tags: subsonic

I am using SubSonic 2.1 for my web application.  It's been working fine until recently I added a table in my SQL Server 2005 database to store user files (such as MS Word, PDF, Jpeg, Gif, Tiff files).  The files are stored in a column called ReportFile varbinary(max).

After SubSonic generates the code, I build it, and get this error:

'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Columns' and no extension method 'Columns' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The offending method:

```
public MyWebApp.ReportFileCollection ReportFiles()
{
    return newMyWebApp.ReportFileCollection().Where(ReportFile.Columns.ReportID, ReportID).Load();
}
```

Then, I checked file ReportFile.cs, and do see that Columns are defined as struct:

```
#region Columns Struct
public struct Columns
{
     public static string ReportFileID = @"ReportFileID";
     public static string FileName = @"FileName";
     public static string ReportID = @"ReportID";
     public static string MimeType = @"MimeType";
     public static string FileSize = @"FileSize";
     public static string FileData = @"FileData";
     public static string UploadDate = @"UploadDate";

}
#endregion
```

I had thought it may have to do with the varbinary(max) column, so I tested generating code with a Test database which also contains a table with a varbinary(max) column, and it worked perfectly.

Because of this error, I have to comment out this ReportFiles method.  Anyone knows about this?  It is mysterious to me. Any workaround?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm running into this problem with certain fields in my table ('TransactionCode', 'Keyword').  Maybe Rob Conery or one of the SubSonic gurus can answer.

Comment: The error would seem to suggest that `ReportFile` is an Array. If you mouse over it what type does Intellisense say it is? Is `ReportFile` a static class with a static property `Columns`?  Actually; what version of SubSonic are you using? And if you are using SS3, what T4 template is generating the code?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like a naming conflict with one of the namespaces that's already been declared. Perhaps the error your seeing isn't telling you the whole truth. You may need to use [regexDictionaryReplace](http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/2.0_Configuration) in the web.config to rename the columns to non-conflicting values.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this server side error you just add the following namespaces,

```
using System.Linq;
```

at the top of your source and make sure you've got a reference to the *System.Core* assembly.